# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping... MessageKit

Tags: ios, swift

I have a struct set up for Messages and each time I got to load messages in app, I receive an unexpectedly found nil error on this line of code -->

```
var chatPartnerId: String {
        return isFromCurrentUser ? toID! : fromID! // where I get the error
    }
```

**I can't figure out what Im doing wrong here at all.**

Here's the class setup:

```
struct Message: MessageType {
  let id: String?
    
  var messageId: String {
    return id ?? UUID().uuidString
  }
    
    var content: String?
    var toID: String?
    var fromID: String?
    var isFromCurrentUser = Bool()
    
    var chatPartnerId: String {
        return isFromCurrentUser ? toID! : fromID!
    }
    
  let sentDate: Date
  let sender: SenderType
  var image: UIImage?
  var downloadURL: URL?
    
  var kind: MessageKind {
    if let image = image {
      let mediaItem = ImageMediaItem(image: image)
      return .photo(mediaItem)
    } else {
        return .text(content ?? "")
    }
  }

    init(user: User, content: String, fromID: String, toID: String) {
    sender = Sender(senderId: user.uid!, displayName: user.name!)
    self.content = content
        self.fromID = fromID
        self.toID = toID
    sentDate = Date()
    id = nil
  }

  init(user: User, image: UIImage) {
    sender = Sender(senderId: user.uid!, displayName: user.name!)
    self.image = image
    content = ""
      fromID = ""
      toID = ""
    sentDate = Date()
    id = nil
  }

  init?(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
    let data = document.data()
    guard
      let sentDate = data["created"] as? Timestamp,
      let senderId = data["senderId"] as? String,
      let fromID = data["fromID"] as? String,
      let toID = data["toID"] as? String,
      let senderName = data["senderName"] as? String
    else {
      return nil
    }

    id = document.documentID
    self.sentDate = sentDate.dateValue()
    sender = Sender(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName)
      self.isFromCurrentUser = fromID == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    

    if let content = data["content"] as? String {
      self.content = content
      downloadURL = nil
    } else if let urlString = data["url"] as? String, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
      downloadURL = url
      content = ""
    } else {
      return nil
    }
      
      
  }
}

// MARK: - DatabaseRepresentation
extension Message: DatabaseRepresentation {
  var representation: [String: Any] {
    var rep: [String: Any] = [
      "created": sentDate,
      "senderId": sender.senderId,
      "fromID": fromID,
      "toID": toID,
      "senderName": sender.displayName
    ]

    if let url = downloadURL {
      rep["url"] = url.absoluteString
    } else {
      rep["content"] = content
    }

    return rep
  }
}

// MARK: - Comparable
extension Message: Comparable {
  static func == (lhs: Message, rhs: Message) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }

  static func < (lhs: Message, rhs: Message) -> Bool {
    return lhs.sentDate < rhs.sentDate
  }
}
```

Comment: You’re force unwrapping an optional which isn’t set at this point which is leading to a crash. You should avoid ! - unwraps and use other techniques to unwrap an optional value

Comment: Think of the force-unwrap `!` operator as the "crash if nil" operator. That's what it does. You should avoid it completely until you really understand optionals. (It's only safe to force-unwrap if you are certain the optional you are unwrapping will never contain a nil.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `toID` and `fromID` are optionals and may be `nil`. Avoid force unwrapping the optional (and actually avoid force unwrapping anything else, with very rare exceptions), like you do in the problematic statement.

Instead, you can:

1. Don't be afraid to return an optional:

```
var chatPartnerId: String? { // <-- returns optional
    return isFromCurrentUser ? toID : fromID
}
```

In many cases it's much better to deal with the `nil` as a condition that helps you understand the state of the app. For example `nil` may mean you should skip the processing of such message.

2. You can return a default bogus ID, or an empty string:

```
var chatPartnerId: String { 
    guard let id = isFromCurrentUser ? toID : fromID else {
        return "" // <-- returns bogus ID
    }
    return id
}
```

3. You can change the property to be required:

```
    var toID: String // <-- not optional
    var fromID: String // <-- not optional
```

Looking at all of your `init`s I see none of them allows these paramters to be `nil`. So you don't need to make them optional.

Comment: Hey @rapiddevice, so I took your suggestion but now Im dealing with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527878/variable-used-before-being-initialized-error-when-retrieving-data?noredirect=1#comment133256516_75527878